# I have two Comboboxes, combobox #2's data is not able to be selected

Tags: c#, combobox

I have 2 combo boxes which are databound, which I think is the issue here but was hoping some one can take a gander and let me know their thoughts. I cant seem to figure this one out and tried everything I could search for. When I make a secondary selection in combobox2, the data will not update and will remain as the primary selection within combobox2. (sorry, super bad at explaining this but if you need me to clarify please let me know!)

Form Load with combobox1:

```
    private void answers_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            string conn2 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ConnectionString;
            //The query to use
            string query2 = "SELECT trial_id,description FROM trials";
            SqlConnection connection2 = new SqlConnection(conn2);
            //Create a Data Adapter
            SqlDataAdapter dadapter2 = new SqlDataAdapter(query2, connection2);
            //Create the dataset
            DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
            //Open the connection
            connection2.Open();
            //Fill the Data Adapter
            dadapter2.Fill(ds2, "trials");
            connection2.Close();
            //Bind the datagridview with the data set
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "trial_id";
            comboBox1.BindingContext = new BindingContext();
            comboBox1.ValueMember = "description";
            comboBox1.DataSource = ds2.Tables["trials"];


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // write exception info to log or anything else
            MessageBox.Show("Error occured!");
        }
```

}

Combobox2 using the selectionchangecommitted event in comboxbox1selectionchangecomitted event:

```
    private void comboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        #region Questions_Start

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ConnectionString))
        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "SELECT question1 FROM trials WHERE trial_id ='" + comboBox1.Text + "'";
            connection.Open();
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                    question1.Text = reader["question1"].ToString();
                connection.Close();
            }
        }

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ConnectionString))
        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "SELECT question2 FROM trials WHERE trial_id ='" + comboBox1.Text + "'";
            connection.Open();
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                    question2.Text = reader["question2"].ToString();
                connection.Close();
            }
        }



        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ConnectionString))
        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "SELECT question3 FROM trials WHERE trial_id ='" + comboBox1.Text + "'";
            connection.Open();
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                    question3.Text = reader["question3"].ToString();
                connection.Close();
            }
        }



        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ConnectionString))
        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "SELECT question4 FROM trials WHERE trial_id ='" + comboBox1.Text + "'";
            connection.Open();
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                    question4.Text = reader["question4"].ToString();
                connection.Close();
            }
        }


        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ConnectionString))
        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "SELECT question5 FROM trials WHERE trial_id ='" + comboBox1.Text + "'";
            connection.Open();
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                    question5.Text = reader["question5"].ToString();
                connection.Close();
            }
        }



        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ConnectionString))
        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "SELECT question6 FROM trials WHERE trial_id ='" + comboBox1.Text + "'";
            connection.Open();
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                    question6.Text = reader["question6"].ToString();
                connection.Close();
            }
        }

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ConnectionString))
        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "SELECT question7 FROM trials WHERE trial_id ='" + comboBox1.Text + "'";
            connection.Open();
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                    question7.Text = reader["question7"].ToString();
                connection.Close();
            }
        }



        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ConnectionString))
        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "SELECT question8 FROM trials WHERE trial_id ='" + comboBox1.Text + "'";
            connection.Open();
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                    question8.Text = reader["question8"].ToString();
                connection.Close();
            }
        }


        #endregion

        #region Users_Start
        try
        {


            string conn3 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ConnectionString;
            //The query to use
            string query3 = "SELECT user_id FROM users_enrolled WHERE trial_id ='" + comboBox1.Text + "'";
            SqlConnection connection3 = new SqlConnection(conn3);
            //Create a Data Adapter
            SqlDataAdapter dadapter3 = new SqlDataAdapter(query3, connection3);
            //Create the dataset
            DataSet ds3 = new DataSet();
            //Open the connection
            connection3.Open();
            //Fill the Data Adapter
            dadapter3.Fill(ds3, "users_enrolled");
            connection3.Close();
            //Bind the datagridview with the data set
            comboBox2.DisplayMember = "user_id";
            comboBox2.BindingContext = new BindingContext();
            comboBox2.ValueMember = "trial_id";
            comboBox2.DataSource = ds3.Tables["users_enrolled"];


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // write exception info to log or anything else
            MessageBox.Show("Error occured!");
        }



        #endregion

        #region Answers_Start

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ConnectionString))
        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "SELECT answer1 FROM answers WHERE trial_id ='" + comboBox1.Text + "' AND user_name ='" + comboBox2.Text + "'";
            connection.Open();
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                    answer1.Text = reader["answer1"].ToString();
                connection.Close();
            }
        }

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ConnectionString))
        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "SELECT answer2 FROM answers WHERE trial_id ='" + comboBox1.Text + "' AND user_name ='" + comboBox2.Text + "'";
            connection.Open();
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                    answer2.Text = reader["answer2"].ToString();
                connection.Close();
            }
        }


        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ConnectionString))
        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "SELECT answer3 FROM answers WHERE trial_id ='" + comboBox1.Text + "' AND user_name ='" + comboBox2.Text + "'";
            connection.Open();
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                    answer3.Text = reader["answer3"].ToString();
                connection.Close();
            }
        }

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ConnectionString))
        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "SELECT answer4 FROM answers WHERE trial_id ='" + comboBox1.Text + "' AND user_name ='" + comboBox2.Text + "'";
            connection.Open();
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                    answer4.Text = reader["answer4"].ToString();
                connection.Close();
            }
        }

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ConnectionString))
        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "SELECT answer5 FROM answers WHERE trial_id ='" + comboBox1.Text + "' AND user_name ='" + comboBox2.Text + "'";
            connection.Open();
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                    answer5.Text = reader["answer5"].ToString();
                connection.Close();
            }
        }


        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ConnectionString))
        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "SELECT answer6 FROM answers WHERE trial_id ='" + comboBox1.Text + "' AND user_name ='" + comboBox2.Text + "'";
            connection.Open();
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                    answer6.Text = reader["answer6"].ToString();
                connection.Close();
            }
        }


        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ConnectionString))
        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "SELECT answer7 FROM answers WHERE trial_id ='" + comboBox1.Text + "' AND user_name ='" + comboBox2.Text + "'";
            connection.Open();
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                    answer7.Text = reader["answer7"].ToString();
                connection.Close();
            }
        }


        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ConnectionString))
        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "SELECT answer8 FROM answers WHERE trial_id ='" + comboBox1.Text + "' AND user_name ='" + comboBox2.Text + "'";
            connection.Open();
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                    answer8.Text = reader["answer8"].ToString();
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }

        #endregion
```

Combobox2 SelectionChangeComittedEvent:

```
private void comboBox2_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string conn4 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ConnectionString;
                //The query to use
                string query4 = "SELECT user_id FROM users_enrolled WHERE trial_id ='" + comboBox1.Text + "'";
                SqlConnection connection4 = new SqlConnection(conn4);
                //Create a Data Adapter
                SqlDataAdapter dadapter4 = new SqlDataAdapter(query4, connection4);
                //Create the dataset
                DataSet ds4 = new DataSet();
                //Open the connection
                connection4.Open();
                //Fill the Data Adapter
                dadapter4.Fill(ds4, "users_enrolled");
                connection4.Close();
                //Bind the datagridview with the data set
                comboBox2.DisplayMember = "user_id";
                comboBox2.BindingContext = new BindingContext();
                comboBox2.ValueMember = "trial_id";
                comboBox2.DataSource = ds4.Tables["users_enrolled"];

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // write exception info to log or anything else
                MessageBox.Show("Error occured!");
            }
        }
```

[image]

The image above demonstrates that user test123 is going to be selected but after I click test123 it reverts back to mlewis412.

Thank you all!

Comment: You have the same code in `selectionchangecommitted` event of both the comboboxes. And the code populates data in combobox2. That's why selection is reverted.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya  thank you that was it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the same code in selectionchangecommitted event of both the comboboxes. And the code populates data in combobox2. That's why selection is reverted. – Chetan Ranpariya